# How does localStorage act in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to replicate [this app](http://web.koesbong.com/demo/codingtest/) in order to learn from it, but unfortunately, said replication is not working. I mostly copy-pasted the code from inspecting the source and then pulling all of the files that the script points to (one of the links is broken, but I found it on his GitHub and used it anyways).

Anyways, my replication did not unfortunately work, and I noticed something called "localStorage" in a few of the files that could be it. From my understanding, localStorage is basically something that uses a browser's storage in order to cache data. However, I couldn't find a declaration for this localStorage concept, or anything of the sort.

Now, I am new to this world of HTML/CSS/Javascript, and I was wondering: is localStorage a variable that one has to declare? If not, what is it, exactly? How does one incur localStorage?

Why does the !DOCTYPE html tag automatically allow for the use of localStorage? Additionally, where in the computer is the information for localStorage even stored, then, and how does the browser fetch that information?

Comment: Please Google your question before posting it here. There are thousands and thousands of articles that will tell you all about `localStorage`.

Comment: I know what it is, but Google quite frankly didn't help me with this particular question about declarations. I tried, for hours, to find that answer.

Comment: If you want to learn, then you should stop fooling yourself by copy pasting code. You'll learn little to nothing from that. You learn how to write code by writing code. Yourself.

Comment: I guess different people learn different ways. Some people, such as myself, learn from example. Codeacademy uses this principle of essentially handing the code out to teach people things such as syntax. My goal is to make a task manager app; what better way exists to do that than to look at an existing app? Please be more mindful of others' learning styles and preferences. Just because I'm copy-pasting someone else's code doesn't mean that I'm lazy. On the contrary, actually.

Comment: Copy pasting is not learning by looking at examples, it's not learning at all and instead just copying someone else's work. You also don't learn math by taking your friends homework and handing it in. You can look at it, understand it. But to learn you reproduce and improve yourself. But that differs from copying.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, and I definitely will eventually reproduce my own app (it probably won't even be related to this). In the meantime, however, I'll learn from the app given. This is how I learned both Java and Python, and it simply works for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The localStorage object stores the data with no expiration date. The
>   data will not be deleted when the browser is closed, and will be
>   available the next day, week, or year.

Simple example I used before:

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" value="">
<input type="text" name="last_name"  value="">

localStorage.setItem('first_name',$('[name=first_name]').val());
localStorage.setItem('last_name',$('[name=last_name]').val());
```

Let's say this is a form for shipping details before the checkout page on an online shopping website. Once you fill it out and go to the next page. This will get stored in localStorage and if you were to come back to this page, it will be already populated for you, so you don't have to insert your information again.

**Note:** Internet Explorer 7 and earlier versions, do not support Web Storage.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense. One more quick question; do you have to "declare" or "initialize" the localStorage object anywhere?

Comment: I put a little note there at the end for compatibility. All major browsers support it but you will have to declare `<!DOCTYPE html>` in the beginning of your page. Other than that, you don't have to do anything :) It is ready to use on current browsers.